# Embryonic cells, when can you detect them in vivo? (In order to do whole genome sequencing)

Tags: genomics, embryology, human-genome

I was wondering, when is it possible to extract cells (humans or mice) in order to sequence them and detect diseases.
Extra: Urine of the embryo in humans is excreted in the 16th week, so I guess that then it's possible to extract some embryo cells.

EDIT
In other words, when is it possible to grab enough DNA to know the full genome of the embryo without damaging it?
In order to sequence it and avoid most genetic diseases and regulate the weekly abortion limits.

Thanks

Comment: In vivo or in vitro?

Comment: Sorry, in vivo, now I'll edit.

Comment: So you are discounting human non-invasive pre-natal testing, on the grounds that it uses cell-free DNA?

Comment: @swbarnes2  it depends,  I am especially thinking in the abortions and genetic diseases.

Comment: So, when are there enough cells to grab enough DNA and fully genotype the embryo?, Then you could know most genetic diseases. My question would be answered.

Comment: By "fully genotype" what exactly do you mean?  Are you talking about a large panel like 23andMe, or a whole genome sequence?

Comment: My fault, I didn't  mean genotype, I wanted to say sequencing. Sorry!

Comment: Are you asking about detecting cells or having enough material to do whole genome sequencing?

Comment: @swbarnes2 about having enough material of the embryo to do whole genome sequencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the answer is "it depends what you mean". There is a large existing field ([prenatal genetic diagnostic testing](https://www.acog.org/Patients/FAQs/Prenatal-Genetic-Diagnostic-Tests?IsMobileSet=false)) which trying to diagnose genetic diseases in fetuses using different technologies. These technologies are described more in points 2 and 3 below, whereas point 1 is a somewhat academic statement about the technical capabilities of genomic technology in pure research settings which are currently not really relevant for medical applications.

I can think of 3 different answers to the question as originally posed:

1. With currently available sequencing technology you can never know
   the full genome sequence of a human well enough to see all the potentially damaging variants. The "finished" human reference genome in
   fact has gaps and errors that are constantly being corrected. For
   more information about what "finished" means, see [here](https://genome.cshlp.org/content/12/5/669.full.html). [Only one assembly of a telomere-to-telomere human chromosome exists](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/735928v3) as far as I know, and that's only the X chromosome. Even accepting that this best available technology is good enough, it also relies on things like the ability to isolate lots of high-molecular-weight DNA, which makes it very tough to do on the amount of cells you could get from a newborn without highly invasive procedures such as e.g. sampling fetal tissue in vivo. My guess is that even amniocentesis would be very hard to get good HMW DNA from.
2. With currently available sequencing technology you can however test
   very early [provided you used IVF](https://fertility.womenandinfants.org/treatment/genetic-testing), at least as early as the 100-cell stage
   (probably earlier). This is a chancier method that will miss a lot
   of information but gives you good enough info to diagnose
   aneuploidies or other very obvious variants.
3. Alternately, you can screen [cell-free fetal DNA as early as 7
   weeks](https://dnadots.minipcr.com/dnadots/cell-free-fetal-dna-screening-cffdna) (or possibly earlier). However this does not involve
   isolating cells so it is potentially not what you are thinking
   about. It is somewhat better information than preimplantation
   screening, but rather worse information than you can get from whole
   cells.

Likely none of those are exactly the answer you want, but it's also a less simple question than it appears at first: a) getting cells is hard and probably not necessary for the current tech, and b) the tech isn't actually as good as generally advertised.

Comment: Thanks!, It is a good and really complete answer. Hopefully in the future we will be able of doing a more complete sequence of the embryos or fetus and avoid those diseases developed during the development. Do you know any source (blog, researcher wordpress...) that talk about this area? Or the scientific name of this field? Thanks!! Héctor

Comment: @Héctor - see edit. I think you are interested in prenatal genetic diagnostics. I have added a link to the answer, which you can also see here: https://www.acog.org/Patients/FAQs/Prenatal-Genetic-Diagnostic-Tests?IsMobileSet=false

Comment: Oops, meant to also link to this article: https://obgyn.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/pd.5520 and there is a journal "Prenatal Diagnostics" that you may find useful: https://obgyn.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10970223